# dynamically generated modal with embedded swf content does not trigger the "click to use flash" overlay in safari 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, safari

i am trying to get a flash-games showcase site working again, after Safari 10 changed the game and the old SwfObject does not work anymore.
The site is a simple bootstrap grid with dynamic modals which get created via javascript when a thumbnail is clicked.
In order to trigger "click to use flash" overlay i changed the code from the SwfObject to a simple embed tag. 
However that does not work ...
The created embed looks like this:

```
<embed class="embeddedswf" src="games/game1/swf/game1.swf" width="640" height="480" FlashVars="path=games/game1/swf/&w=945&h=540" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" />
```

and works perfectly in a static site or in other browsers
So i assume, that safari does not like the modal to be created at runtime via JavaScript.

EDIT: If i already enabled flash for the site it works like a charm like in all other browsers.

Does anyone have an idea if there is a solution?
Or do I have to make all the content static?

thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same issue. Your description match up properly. I am also looking for a solution. In my case, I have don't have any option to make it appear staticly...

Comment: did you find a solution? i did not yet ... sigh

Comment: I found out that it was a CSS bug in safari.... I has something to do with position (like top, left, right, bottom). That somewhat worked for me. But, it doesn't work across all version of safari.

I believe this is a bug in Safari.

Comment: The position of the modal, the div or the embed ?

Comment: The position of the div for the whole flash. But, i did not dig deeper.

Comment: any new developements?

Comment: Oh.... I think there might be... If I remember correct, it has something to do with the Mac Retina Display setting. I think when we turned it off, the flash pop-up started to work normally. But, it has been months since and there were 2 or 3 issues like this one... So, I can't remember properly. Bottom line, we gave up fixing it. Our plan is to let customer know that they should use Chrome/Firefox instead.

Comment: Thats the same thing I did... Let the user know whats up.